# C Version of a Client/Server application

Tags: c, socket

Starting to write an article about Socket Programing.
So I need a simple C version of a client/server app.

So here it is for review (Also on [github](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/Examples/tree/master/ClientServerCExample))

A linked question is the [C++ version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/125273/507)

## MakeFile

```
all:    client server

.PHONY:         all
.INTERMEDIATE:  %.o

CFLAGS  += -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic 

client: client.o common.o
server: server.o common.o

server.o:   server.c common.h
client.o:   client.c common.h
common.o:   common.c common.h
```

## Common.h

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

#include <stddef.h>

#define QUOTE_(X)       #X
#define QUOTE(X)        QUOTE_(X)

extern char const* socketError;

int serverSocket();
int clientSocket(char const* host);
int sendMessage(int socket, char const* buffer, size_t size);
int getMessage(int socket, char* buffer, size_t size);

#endif
```

## common.cpp

```
#include "common.h"

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char const* failedSocket = "Failed: socket()";
char const* failedBind   = "Failed: bind()";
char const* failedListen = "Failed: listen()";
char const* failedConnect= "Failed: connect()";
char const* socketError = "None";

int serverSocket()
{
    int socketId = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socketId == -1)
    {
        socketError = failedSocket;
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    bzero((char*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family       = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port         = htons(8080);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr  = INADDR_ANY;
    if (bind(socketId, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) != 0)
    {
        socketError = failedBind;
        close(socketId);
        return -1;
    }

    if(listen(socketId, 5) != 0)
    {
        socketError = failedListen;
        close(socketId);
        return -1;
    }
    return socketId;
}

int clientSocket(char const* host)
{
    int socketId = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socketId == -1)
    {
        socketError = failedSocket;
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    socklen_t addrSize = sizeof(serverAddr);
    bzero((char*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family       = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port         = htons(8080);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr  = inet_addr(host);
    if (connect(socketId, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, addrSize) != 0)
    {
        socketError = failedConnect;
        close(socketId);
        return -1;
    }
    return socketId;
}

/*
 * Returns:
 *      0:      OK.     Message was sent with no errors.
 *      -1:     Error.  Something went wrong. See errno
 */
int sendMessage(int socket, char const* buffer, size_t size)
{
    size_t sentSize = 0;
    while(sentSize != size)
    {
        size_t sent = write(socket, buffer + sentSize, size - sentSize);
        if (sent == -1u && errno == EINTR)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (sent == -1u)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (sent == 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        sentSize += sent;
    }
    return 0;
}

/*
 * Returns:
 *      0       OK.     End of Message. No data in buffer.
 *      >0      MORE.   Data in buffer. Value is number of bytes read.
 *      -1:     Error.  Something went wrong. See errno
 */
int getMessage(int socket, char* buffer, size_t size)
{
    size_t getSize = 0;
    do
    {
        size_t get = read(socket, buffer + getSize, size - getSize);
        if (get == -1u && errno == EINTR)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (get == -1u)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (get == 0)
        {
            return getSize;
        }
        getSize += get;
    }
    while(getSize != size);
    return getSize;
}
```

## server.c

```
#include "common.h"

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE     1024
int main()
{
    int socketId = serverSocket();
    if (socketId == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n%s\n", socketError, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    struct  sockaddr_storage    serverStorage;
    socklen_t                   addr_size   = sizeof serverStorage;
    int                         finished    = 0;
    while(!finished)
    {
        int newSocket = accept(socketId, (struct sockaddr*)&serverStorage, &addr_size);
        if (newSocket == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed: accept()\n%s\n", strerror(errno));
            close(socketId);
            exit(1);
        }

        static char const*  fullBufferFormat = "%." QUOTE(SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE) "s";
        static char const*  endBufferFormat  = "%s\n";

        int         get;
        char        buffer[SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE];
        while((get = getMessage(newSocket, buffer, SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
        {
            char const* format = get != SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE ? endBufferFormat : fullBufferFormat;
            fprintf(stdout, format, buffer);
        }

        char const* msg     = get == 0 ? "OK" : "ERROR";
        if (sendMessage(newSocket, msg, strlen(msg) + 1) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed: sendMessage\n%s\n", strerror(errno));
            close(newSocket);
            close(socketId);
            exit(1);
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "Message Complete\n");

        close(newSocket);
    }
    close(socketId);
}
```

## client.c

```
#include "common.h"

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define CLIENT_BUFFER_SIZE     1024
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: client <host> <Message>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int socketId = clientSocket(argv[1]);
    if (socketId == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n%s\n", socketError, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    if (sendMessage(socketId, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]) + 1) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed: sendMessage()\n%s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(socketId);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (shutdown(socketId, SHUT_WR) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed: shutdown()\n%s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(socketId);
        exit(1);
    }

    static char const*  fullBufferFormat = "%s %." QUOTE(SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE) "s";
    static char const*  endBufferFormat  = "%s %s\n";

    int     get;
    char    buffer[CLIENT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    while((get = getMessage(socketId, buffer, CLIENT_BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
        char const* format = get != CLIENT_BUFFER_SIZE ? endBufferFormat : fullBufferFormat;
        fprintf(stdout, format, "Response from server", buffer);
    }

    if (get == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed: getMessage()\n%s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    close(socketId);
}
```

### CentOS 7:

From @pacmaninbw in the comments (so it is readable)

```
cc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -c -o client.o client.c client.c
In function ‘main’:
client.c:19:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=pedantic] int socketId = clientSocket(argv[1]); 
client.c:39:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=pedantic] static char const* fullBufferFormat = "%s %." QUOTE(SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE) "s";
client.c:56:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type] }
```

Comment: CentOS 7: cc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic    -c -o client.o client.c
client.c: In function ‘main’:
client.c:19:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=pedantic]
     int socketId = clientSocket(argv[1]);
     ^
client.c:39:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=pedantic]
     static char const*  fullBufferFormat = "%s %." QUOTE(SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE) "s";
     ^
client.c:56:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^                                       from the zip file on github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**General**
Nice clean presentation.

1. A potential infinite loop.   Consider some limitation on repetitive `EINTR` conditions.  I would expect a `errno==0` before the `write()`.

   ```
   while(sentSize != size) {
     errno = 0;  // add
     size_t sent = write(socket, buffer + sentSize, size - sentSize);
     if (sent == -1u && errno == EINTR) {
       continue;
     }
   ```
2. Name space: The names of functions, variables and macros in `common.h` share no cohesive naming scheme.  This makes it unclear of their source when used.  The use of `QUOTE()` and `common.h`  is something that easily could collide with other libraries.  Suggest something like `CVersion.h` with `CVersion_serverSocket()`,`CVersion_QUOTE()`, etc.
3. Rather than `extern char const* socketError;`, make it a function: `char const* socketError();` to prevent user code from changing it.
4. `bzero()` is not standard C, yet implementations I find use `void bzero(void *s, size_t n);`, thus the cast is not needed.  Also parens not needed with `sizeof variable`

   ```
   // bzero((char*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
   bzero(&serverAddr, sizeof serverAddr );
   ```
5. Alternate initialization

   ```
   //struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
   //bzero((char*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
   struct sockaddr_in serverAddr = { 0} ;
   ```
6. Avoid naked magic numbers.  Consider self-documenting code

   ```
   // htons(8080)
   #define PORT_DUJOUR 8080
   htons(PORT_DUJOUR);

   // listen(socketId, 5)
   #define LISTIN_BACKLOG 5
   listen(socketId, LISTIN_BACKLOG)
   ```
7. I have a suspicion that usage of `format = get != SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE ? endBufferFormat : fullBufferFormat;` may result in the final `getMessage()` not printing a `’\n’`.

**Minor**

1. Recommend using `bool` for Boolean like variables.

   ```
   // int finished    = 0;
   //while(!finished)
   #include <stdbool.h>
   bool finished  = false;
   while(!finished)
   ```
2. Style: Prefer the explicit function signature `int serverSocket(void)` vs `int serverSocket()`.
3. Style: The spacing used in the below adds little clarity, but adds typing.  Suggest simplification.

   ```
   // int         get;
   // char        buffer[SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE];
   int get;
   char buffer[SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE];
   ```