# C++ Version of a Client/Server application

Tags: c++, socket

Starting to write an article about Socket Programing.
So I need a simple C++ version of a client/server app.

So here it is for review (Also on [github](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/Examples/tree/master/Socket))

A linked question is the [C version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/125272/507)

## Makefile

```
all:    client server

.PHONY:         all
.INTERMEDIATE:  %.o

CC          =  $(CXX)
CXXFLAGS    += -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c++14

client: client.o common.o
server: server.o common.o

server.o:   server.cpp common.h
client.o:   client.cpp common.h
common.o:   common.cpp common.h
```

## common.h

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

class Socket
{
    protected:
        int socketId;
    public:
        Socket(int socketId);
        ~Socket();
        Socket(Socket&&);
        Socket& operator=(Socket&&);
        Socket(Socket const&)               = delete;
        Socket& operator=(Socket const&)    = delete;

        virtual bool sendMessage(std::string const& buffer);
        bool getMessage(std::string& buffer);
};

class Client: public Socket
{
    public:
        Client(std::string const& host);
        virtual bool sendMessage(std::string const& buffer) override;
};

class Server: public Socket
{
    public:
        Server();
        Socket accept();
};

#endif
```

## common.cpp

```
#include "common.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>

Socket::Socket(int socketId)
    : socketId(socketId)
{
    if (socketId == -1)
    {
        std::stringstream message("Failed: socket()\n");
        message << strerror(errno);
        throw std::runtime_error(message.str());
    }
}

Socket::~Socket()
{
    if (socketId != -1)
    {
        ::close(socketId);
    }
}

Socket::Socket(Socket&& move)
    : socketId(move.socketId)
{
    move.socketId   = -1;
}

Socket& Socket::operator=(Socket&& move)
{
    std::swap(socketId, move.socketId);
    return *this;
}

bool Socket::sendMessage(std::string const& buffer)
{
    std::size_t size     = buffer.size() + 1;
    std::size_t sentSize = 0;
    while(sentSize != size)
    {
        std::size_t sent = ::write(socketId, buffer.data() + sentSize, size - sentSize);
        if (sent == -1u && errno == EINTR)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (sent == -1u)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (sent == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        sentSize += sent;
    }
    return true;
}

bool Socket::getMessage(std::string& buffer)
{
    buffer.clear();

    char tmp[1024];
    std::size_t get;
    while((get= ::read(socketId, tmp, sizeof(tmp))))
    {
        if (get == -1u && errno == EINTR)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (get == -1u)
        {
            return false;
        }
        buffer.append(tmp, get);
    }
    return true;
}

Client::Client(std::string const& hostname)
    : Socket(::socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))
{
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    socklen_t addrSize = sizeof(serverAddr);
    bzero((char*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family       = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port         = htons(8080);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr  = inet_addr(hostname.c_str());

    if (::connect(socketId, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, addrSize) != 0)
    {
        std::stringstream message("Failed: connect()\n");
        message << strerror(errno);
        throw std::runtime_error(message.str());
    }
}

bool Client::sendMessage(std::string const& buffer)
{
    bool result = Socket::sendMessage(buffer);
    if (result)
    {
        if (::shutdown(socketId, SHUT_WR) != 0)
        {
            std::stringstream message("Failed: shutdown()\n");
            message << strerror(errno);
            throw std::runtime_error(message.str());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

Server::Server()
    : Socket(::socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))
{
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    bzero((char*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family       = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port         = htons(8080);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr  = INADDR_ANY;

    if (::bind(socketId, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) != 0)
    {
        std::stringstream message("Failed: bind()\n");
        message << strerror(errno);
        throw std::runtime_error(message.str());
    }

    if(::listen(socketId, 5) != 0)
    {
        std::stringstream message("Failed: listen()\n");
        message << strerror(errno);
        throw std::runtime_error(message.str());
    }
}

Socket Server::accept()
{
    struct  sockaddr_storage    serverStorage;
    socklen_t                   addr_size   = sizeof serverStorage;

    int newSocket = ::accept(socketId, (struct sockaddr*)&serverStorage, &addr_size);
    if (newSocket == -1)
    {
        std::cerr << fprintf(stdout, "%s\n%s\n", "Failed to accept", strerror(errno));
    }
    return Socket(newSocket);
}
```

## server.cpp

```
#include "common.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    static std::string okMsg    = "OK";
    static std::string errorMsg = "ERROR";
    try
    {
        Server  server;
        int                         finished    = 0;
        while(!finished)
        {
            Socket      connection = server.accept();

            std::string buffer;
            bool    ok = false;
            if (connection.getMessage(buffer))
            {
                std::cout << buffer << "\n"
                          << "Message Complete\n";
                ok = true;
            }

            if (!connection.sendMessage(ok ? okMsg : errorMsg))
            {
                std::cerr << "Send Message Failed\n" << strerror(errno) << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        throw;
    }
}
```

## client.cpp

```
#include "common.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <Message>\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    try
    {
        Client  client(argv[1]);

        if (!client.sendMessage(argv[2]))
        {
            std::stringstream message("Failed: sendMessage()\n");
            message << strerror(errno);
            throw std::runtime_error(message.str());
        }

        std::string     buffer;
        if (client.getMessage(buffer))
        {
            std::cout << "Response from server: " << buffer << "\n";
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I don't think `common.h` may mention `Client` or `Server`. I also recommend to rename it to `socket.h`, and restrict it to *common* `Socket` functionality: `Socket()`, `~Socket()`, `getMessage()` and `sendMessage()`.

  Along the same line, I don't see a reason to override `sendMessage` in `Client`.
- `read` and `write` return `ssize_t`, and so should be `get`, `size` and `sentSize`.
- `EPIPE` is not a C++ exception. You may want to set up a corresponding handler.
- I don't see how the example code works at all. Client never closes the connection (unless it is forcefully terminated from the outside), and the server is stuck in waiting to read.
- Continuation after `EINTR` is at least questionable, but perhaps you address it in the article.
- I honestly don't understand the rationale of `Socket` move constructor.

Comment: Why is continuing after `EINTR` bad.

Comment: @LokiAstari It is not _bad_, but when a user does ^C, she expects the application to stop.

Comment: <ctrl>-C has nothing to do with EINTR. The SIGINT (the result of hitting <ctrl>-C) signal by default is fatal and causes program termination. The EINTR is usually the result of a timer signal or a hardware interrupt (like data arriving from a socket or hard disk). Even if you override the default action of SIGINT with a `signal()` call you are well beyond the scope of this discussion. So yes the correct action on EINTR is to re-call read().

Comment: @LokiAstari Sorry I am afraid you don't follow. EINTR is not a result of anything, but a manifestation the the system call being interrupted. The reasons for interruption could be many. A well-behaving application finds out that reason and reacts appropriately (that is retry, or give up). One of the reasons is a signal raised by the termio driver (aka SIGINT), and the _expected_ behavior is to give up, because the user said so. In other situations it might be OK to retry.

Comment: @vpn how do you find what signal happened? I am unaware on how to detect this.

Answer (score 0):

- You should avoid exposing `<arpa/inet.h>` in a public header file if you're not calling the system functions directly from outside. The objective here is to simplify a lower-level system interface, so the user code need not know about the underlaying socket API.
- `Socket` base class is missing a virtual destructor, which is going to be an evident problem as soon as people start dynamically allocating and deleting those objects.
- Why is the port number hardcoded to `8080`? Seems like it could very easily be a constructor argument. You can always default it to `8080`, but allowing it to be user-provided seems logical.
- I suggest sticking to C++-style casts even when you're just doing pointer reinterpretation. If nothing else, a `reinterpret_cast` is much easier to search for and more visible.
- You could take advantage of `std::string`s `+` operator to make your throws one-liners:

  ```
  throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed: socket()\n") + std::strerror(errno));
  ```
- This seems like a typo:

  > ```
  > if (newSocket == -1)
  > {
  >     std::cerr << fprintf(stdout, "%s\n%s\n", "Failed to accept", strerror(errno));
  > }
  > ```

  You're printing the return of `fprintf`, which is the number of characters written, not the formatted string. The string itself is output to stdout. Perhaps you meant to format the string `sprintf`-style and then send to `cerr`? Again, that could be done more neatly with string's `+` operator.
- No reason to still use `bzero`. [Stick to standard `memset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097088/1198654) or simply call the implicit constructor directly:

  ```
  sockaddr_in serverAddr{};
  ```
- I don't particularly like the idea of re-throwing an exception from `main`. You have handled the exception (by logging a message), so why not return with an error code (`EXIT_FAILURE`)?
- It eludes me why `okMsg` and `errorMsg` strings are `static`. `const` would make sense there, but otherwise, they already have program lifetime from being declared inside `main`.

---

Apart from these nitpickings, my knowledge of networking is very limited, so I apologize for not providing any feedback on that. Hope this was of use.